# sklearn pipeline not remembering its state when applied on the testing set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When calling the `fit_transform` method of my pipeline on the training set and then the transform method on the testing set, the pipeline is updating its internal state according to the testing set, instead of simply applying what was learnt on the training set.


E.g. given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sex':['female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female','neutral', 'male'],
    'Survived':['no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
})
```

And having it split into X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test:

*Important: Please note that I'm splitting in a way that only the test set has the value "neutral".*

```
X_train = df.loc[:4,'Sex']
y_train = df.loc[:4,'Survived']

X_test = df.loc[5:, 'Sex']
y_test = df.loc[5:, 'Survived']
```

Below I created a transformer called `Dummifier` and inserted in my pipeline (the pipeline has here only one method for the sake of simplicity):

```
class Dummifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_dummies = pd.get_dummies(X)

        return X_dummies


my_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('get_dummies', Dummifier())
])
```

Now, when I called the `fit_transform` in my training set and then the transform method on the testing set, the given output is the below:

```
X_train_trans = my_pipe.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test_trans = my_pipe.transform(X_test)

Output:
    female male neutral
5   1      0    0
6   0      0    1
7   0      1    0
```

**Question:** Since there was no value "neutral" in the training set, why is the transformer creating now a column "neutral" in the testing set?

**The expected output is:**

```
Output:
    female male 
5   1      0    
6   0      0    
7   0      1
```

**I've already try** to use the `OneHotEncoder` from sklearn but the output is basically the same.

Comment: It is just because your transform method does not use any state, and pd.get_dummies does not have a state.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? I thought when I call the method "fit_transform", my pipeline object would learn from the data and store this state. When I would call then "transform", the pipeline would take this previous state to transform the new data, as I'm using the same pipeline object.

Comment: Yes sure but your transform does not use any state, it just calls pd.get_dummies, where in that code are you using the state learned in fit_transform?

Comment: I see what you mean but I can't figure out how to translate that into the code. That's exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`OneHotEncoder`'s `handle_unknown` param needs to be set as `ignore` for your requirement. May be this can help!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sex': ['female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female',
            'female', 'neutral', 'male'],
    'Survived': ['no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
})


X_train = df.loc[:4, 'Sex'].to_frame()
y_train = df.loc[:4, 'Survived']

X_test = df.loc[5:, 'Sex'].to_frame()
y_test = df.loc[5:, 'Survived']


my_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('get_dummies', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

my_pipe.fit_transform(X_train)

print(my_pipe.transform(X_test).toarray())


# [[1. 0.]
#  [0. 0.]
#  [0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code as-is, your two outputs for the transforms are as follows:

**X_train_trans**

```
    female  male
0     1      0
1     0      1
2     0      1
3     0      1
4     1      0
```

**X_test_trans**

```
    female  male  neutral
5     1      0       0
6     0      0       1
7     0      1       0
```

Your question is: why is the transformer creating now a column "neutral" in the testing set? It looks like the reason is because you declare the X_test_trans set to be `X_test_trans = my_pipe.transform(X_test)`, which takes in the `X_test` data, which is as follows:

**X_test**

```
5     female
6    neutral
7       male
```

The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. So let's think of a solution:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sex':['female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female','neutral', 'male'],
    'Survived':['no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
})

features = pd.DataFrame(OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df['Sex'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray())
```

The one-hot encoder will take your three categories and convert them into a format the learning algo will recognise. After this stage, you can then begin to split your data into test and train [using train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

features = pd.DataFrame(OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df['Sex'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray())
labels = df['Survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels)
```

Comment: I can't hot-encode the variable and then "train_test_split" it, because the testing data will be leaked, resulting in over-optimistic performance.

Comment: Good point. I recommend taking a look at the answer provided by @Venkatachalam